# How to change font of code in PyCharm?

Tags: fonts, text-editor, ide

PyCharm Community Edition 3.1.3 on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. Can't find where to change the font of code in PyCharm.

```
File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font > Editor Font
```

is inactive. I can only change font size by setting

```
File > Settings > Editor > [v] Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel
```

but how to change font style/type (`<somefont>` -> `Courier New`)?

By the way, how to disable spell check? It's non-sense to check spelling in filenames and programming code.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured this one out myself. You need to create your own scheme based on one of the predefined (and locked) ones.

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Regards
James